# Error when trying to find MLE for a Geometric Distribution

Tags: r

So I'm given a task in R that says to find MLE for a random value X that has a geometric distribution using the values given in the vector:

```
> x<-c(4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 8, 3, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 2, 2, 3)
```

Here is the function for the MLE:

```
> log.L<-function(p=0.3){
+ n<-length(x)
+ (sum(x)-n)*log(1-p)+n*log(p)
+ }
```

And here is the call:

```
> library(stats4)
> fir<-mle(log.L)
```

However when I make the call I get the following error:

```
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
non-finite finite-difference value [1]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Geometric has a closed form for its parameters jsut do: `length(x)/(sum(x-1)+length(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the first argument is

> minuslogl - Function to calculate **negative** log-likelihood.

Hence, instead we need

```
log.L <- function(p = 0.3) {
  n <- length(x)
  -((sum(x) - n) * log(1 - p) + n * log(p))
}
mle(log.L)
#
# Call:
# mle(minuslogl = log.L)
#
# Coefficients:
#   p 
# 0.3
```

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. Do I need to always add a minus when calculating MLE?

Comment: @DavidMason, MLE, by definition, means maximizing the likelihood function or any other strictly increasing transformation of it (such as log-likelihood), say L. Naturally, instead of maximizing L, you can minimize -L. So, it all depends on the implementation.. `mle` requires a negative log-likelihood, so that's what has to be provided.